# Expanding a post with a large code block in profile pages breaks the design

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

After expanding a post that contains a large code block in a profile, the design of the page breaks and creates a horizontal scroll.

Collapsing the question afterwards does not fix the design, and the design stays broken until I refresh the page.

I'm on Firefox in Ubuntu. I can reproduce the issue in Chromium as well.

I can also reproduce this issue on Stack Overflow, so it doesn't seem to be exclusive to Ask Ubuntu.

[image: Expanded post in actions in profile page]

[image: Collapsed posts in actions in profile page]